# Cant Receive the Push Notification - FCM + Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am currently working on a project, which is like the tiktok clone, and wanna add a feature: sending notifications to the video's owner when someone liked the video of the video owner, followed some videos on YouTube, it works fine when send the notifications from Firebase cloud messaging (sending test messages from the firebase platform), but it did not work when clicked on the like button

```
Future <void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    if(message == null) return;

    print(message.notification?.title);
  }

  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

class NotificationController {

  final authController = Get.find<AuthenticationController>();
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  Future<void> updateFCMToken(String userID) async {
    try {
      String? newToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      if (newToken != null) {
        // Update the FCM token in Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(userID)
            .update({'token': newToken});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error updating FCM token: $e");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug see when notification is sent does the `onMessage` trigger. Also need to be make sure the device token is correct. And u need to use real ios device for testing `firebase messaging`